# "type is not assignable" when trying to spread an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and stuck with a problem when trying to spread an object:

```
interface Employee  {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

let data: Employee ={
    id: 1,
    name: 'name'
}

const fun = (values: Employee) => {
  data = {...data, values}
}
```

It throws the error:

```
Type '{ values: Employee; id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Employee'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'values' does not exist in type 'Employee'
```

What I am doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: `data = {...data, ...values}` it's not TypeScript issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you directly put the `values` object. `data` is of type Employee, it can take id and name as properties, not objects. If you try to add the `values` object it will throw an error.

Replace it

```
const fun = (values: Employee) => {
   data = {...data, values}
}
```

With

```
const fun = (values: Employee) => {
   data = {...data, ...values}
}
```